# gopls returns the error "gopls: no packages returned: packages.Load error" for github.com/Shopify/sarama

Tags: go, sarama

I've checked out the `main` branch of [`github.com/Shopify/sarama`](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama) (at commit `947343309601b4eb3c2fa3e7d15d701b503dd491` ) but I notice that in VS Code I can't "Go to definition" as usual. If I hover over the package name `sarama` in `functional_consumer_group_test.go`, I get the linter warning

```
No packages found for open file /Users/kurtpeek/go/src/github.com/Shopify/sarama/functional_consumer_group_test.go: <nil>.
If this file contains build tags, try adding "-tags=<build tag>" to your gopls "buildFlags" configuration (see (https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/settings.md#buildflags-string).
Otherwise, see the troubleshooting guidelines for help investigating (https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/troubleshooting.md).go list
```

(See screenshot below).

[image]

From the command line, if I try to `gopls` that file, I get a similar error:

```
> gopls check functional_consumer_group_test.go 
gopls: no packages returned: packages.Load error
```

I suspect this has something to do with the build constraints (https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints) in that file, from https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/blob/947343309601b4eb3c2fa3e7d15d701b503dd491/functional_consumer_group_test.go#L1-L2,

```golang
//go:build functional
// +build functional
```

It's not clear to me, however, how to modify my VS Code `settings.json` to pass these build constraints. Does anyone know how to get this functional test to build?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following https://www.ryanchapin.com/configuring-vscode-to-use-build-tags-in-golang-to-separate-integration-and-unit-test-code/, I had to create a `.vscode/settings.json` file in the repository's root directory and add the following contents:

```json
{
    "go.buildFlags": [
        "-tags=functional"
    ],
    "go.testTags": "functional",
}
```

Now VS Code works like normal in that file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `go clean -cache`?

And this link may help:
https://github.com/golang/go/issues/42353

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me!
by adding it in `.vscode/settings.json`

```
{
    "gopls.env": {
        "GOFLAGS": "-tags=test"
    }
}
```